# Affixed Sidebar Position Does not Alter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble using the Bootstra Affix plugin. I want my side menu to be affixed but always stay below the header and above the footer of my document, so I've used the `data-offset-top` and `data-offset-bottom` HTML5 Data Attributes to keep the menu away from both.

This all works fine until I scroll the page to the bottom, at which point the menu jumps back to the top and is not affixed anymore. Once you scroll the page down, the menu will stay above the footer (this is correct). But when scrolling back up, it jumps to the top and stays there.

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyXJQv). How can this be solved?

---

**EDIT:**

After some debugging, I've noticed that the problem seems to be related to `affix-bottom` being reached and the `position:relative` style being applied. When scrolling back up, the style is reset to this, the position doesn't change.

Is some kind of feature or a bug in the Bootstrap script?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Affix, but I do believe you don't have to use both attributes if the parent element finishes before the element you want to avoid colliding with.

Comment: I am not sure that his is correct. In my example the parent element is the `right col-md-6` column which ends before the footer. Without using the `offset-bottom` option, the menu would just scroll above the footer and do not stop before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know whether the behavior I described in my question is an "intended feature" or a bug. However I was able to solve the issue with the following work around.

As described in the edit of my question, the problem is causes by the `position:relative` being applied in `affix-bottom` state but not being removed when switching pack to `affix` state. So I simply added an event handler to completely remove all inline styles when switching to `affix` state. Simply add the following code to the `JS` used in the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyXJQv):

```
$('.right_box').on('affixed.bs.affix', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.removeAttr('style');
});
```

Of course this workaround should only be applied when no other inline styles are used.

Maybe this solution might help someone else how encounters the same problem. If there is a **real** solution to the issue, I would be happy to know it :)